# React github pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am very new to React. I have this as my RouteSwitch

```
const RouteSwitch = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/room" element={<App/>}/>
                <Route path="/topstories" element={<TopStories/>}/>
                <Route path="/GeneralUSA" element={<GeneralUSA/>}/>
                <Route path="/WorldNewspage" element={<WorldNewspage/>}/>
                <Route path="/Covid19page" element={<Covid19page/>}/>
            </Routes> 
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

and I have the following as my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './REDUX/store';
import RouteSwitch from './RouteSwitch';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RouteSwitch/>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

I have the page set correctly on my homepage on my package.json.
My /room page is able to load but when I click on the other pages, it gives me the following:

```
GET https://**mygithub**/topstories 404
```

Comment: are you using`Link` to navigate?

Comment: No, I was using a - forgot to change them and fixed it and it works now! Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

BrowserRouter makes use of the History API to change the URL to *real paths*.

You need to make sure your server can provide those paths. React (and ReactRouter) can't do it for you (because they run client-side).

For static hosting, like Github pages, I recommend using either [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) or [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/). These frameworks both have features that will generate static HTML pages for every URL you are using. This gives performance and SEO benefits as well as working even [if JS fails in the browser](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html).

See [Static HTML Export for Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) or [How Gatsby Works with GitHub Pages](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/previews-deploys-hosting/how-gatsby-works-with-github-pages/) for specific documentation.

Alternatively, as a quick and dirty solution, you can switch to using the [HashRouter](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#hashrouter).